# how to use some features from another app and use it in my app?

Tags: android

i want to create small app witch scan texts from camera and return it in (Edit Text)

this feature(scan texts from camera)is available in Google translate app

so how can i use it in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is set up to do so, you can call startActivityForResult and it will launch, run, and return the result to you via onActivityResult.  If the app isn't set up to work that way, then you can't do it at all.

Comment: what is the mean of ( set up )?

Comment: If its programmed to return a result.

Answer (score 0):

Google is presumably using the same object/character recognition software in the Android Translate app as they do with Google Goggles. There is no official API available from Google to use this service, though you could see if Google Drive's OCR capabilities could be applied to your case.

There are other OCR libraries available, such as Tesseract (https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

You could also look for other image recognition APIs, Camfind (http://camfindapp.com) seems to be an option.